# Why does my recursive function cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, recursion

In the following code I am trying to solve the towers of Hanoi problem. Why am I getting a segmentation fault (core dump)?

Segmentation fault should occur when I try to access unreachable memory but in this program I am not trying to access any unreachable memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void steps(int n, int t, int p)
{
    int i, k = 6 - (p + t);

    if (n == 1) {
        printf("%d-->%d\n", n, t);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            steps(n - 1, k, p);
            printf("%d-->%d\n", n, t);
        } else {
            steps(n - 1, t, k);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    steps(n, 3, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recursion stop condition is required.

Comment: ok so i must wrap rest of code in else! thanks

Comment: I have rejected the edit due to no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: The title is very misleading, please edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing memory you can't access.  It just isn't obvious in the code (like a dangling pointer).  Recursion is tricky; you can easily overflow the stack.  The stack stores information when you enter a function (registers or addresses of parameters, saved values of registers used in the calling function and the called function, and a return pointer (where to jump to when you finish the function) basically.

The stack has a certain size.  It might be quite large, but it is finite.  In recursion, you keep calling the same function from within itself.  If this happens too many times, you will "overflow the stack" -- that is, try to "push" more info onto the stack when it is already full, which means at an address *past the end of the stack* -- memory you may not have access to.  (If you do have access to it, you maybe overwriting one of your variables or some such.)

When you have recursed far enough, you must return from your function without calling it again.  Probably in your n==1 "if".

Answer (score -2):

In the base case of your recursion, you do not have any return statement so your code goes on for infinite time(time limit exceeded), you should try like this:

```
if(n==1)
{
    printf("%d-->%d\n", n, t);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: There is no time limit and that is not the segfault

Comment: It doesn't go on for infinite time. It causes a stack overflow.

Comment: yeah, without return statement, it causes stack overflow. Am i right?

Comment: Although its works but i suggest to Rahul read [Segmentation fault](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html) to learn some important things about Seg-Fault.